# Accessing ViewModel properties in ASP.NET Core controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I've been following an [EF core tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#add-office-to-instructors-page)  on basic CRUD operations, and am having trouble with getting data from my ViewModel.

I'm following their recommended practice of using `TryUpdateModel` (or in my specific case, `TryUpdateModelAsync`) in the following action.

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditPost(int id)
{
    var versionToUpdate = await _context.Versions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == id);

    var editModel = new VersionEditModel() { Version = versionToUpdate };

    if (await TryUpdateModelAsync(
        editModel.Version,
        "Version",
        a => a.Name,
        ...further code removed for brevity
```

In the past, I would have passed the model itself in action signature, i.e.

`public async Task<IActionResult> EditPost(VersionEditModel editModel)`

But the recommendation in the tutorial was to use just the ID, fetch the item from the database and run `TryUpdateModel` against it.

This all works, but I want to access a value that has been `POST`ed to the action as part of the ViewModel, but I can't seem to access it.

If I add the model to the signature as an additional parameter, like this

`public async Task<IActionResult> EditPost(int id, VersionEditModel editModel)`

I can access it using `editModel`, but the `TryUpdateAsync` no longer works properly.

I assume there must be a way to get to this data, but I can't figure out the right way to get to it.

My main problem has been trying to find the right words to explain my issue and what I want, so please ask for clarification if something doesn't make sense.

Comment: You may have to implement your own custom ValueProvider - see https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/97fc7a/smart-working-with-custom-value-providers-in-Asp-Net-mvc/ for some pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up passing the parameters in like so

```
public async Task<IActionResult> EditPost(int id, 
    int[] myListOfInts, 
    int myInt,
    bool myBool)
```

Which is then picked up automatically based on the name. So in my ViewModel I had the following properties

```
//other properties removed for brevity
public int MyInt{ get; set; }
public List<int> MyListOfInts{ get; set; } = new();
public bool MyBool{ get; set; }
//other properties removed for brevity
```

When these are `POST`ed to the endpoint, the model binder automatically picks them up. Its not ideal as a name change in the ViewModel will break the automatic model binding, but it works.